# Inequality involving trace and operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Here's a simple question for which I can't find an answer. Let $W$ be a square real matrix with eigenvalues all real and positive ($W$ is not necessarily symmetric nor diagonalizable) and $A$ a real matrix of same size (no assumptions are made on $A$). Is it true that 
$$ \operatorname{Tr}(AW) \leq \vert \vert\vert A \vert \vert\vert \operatorname{Tr}(W)   $$
where $ \vert \vert\vert A \vert \vert\vert = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert = 1} \Vert A x \Vert$? (the norm $\Vert . \Vert$ is the Euclidean norm)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know. But if it's wrong, it is very likely that you can find a counterexample in the 2×2 case. You might try it out with $W$ already on Jordan normal form and see what you can get.

Comment: Do you mean that every eigenvalue of $W$ is real and positive or that every real eigenvalue of $W$ is positive?

Comment: I work with real matrices with real eigenvalues, thanks for pointing it out, I edit.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen thanks for the advice but honestly I have no clue where to start even in the $2 \times 2$ case...

Comment: I see you got an answer, but the general advice is this: Play around, see what you can get. You can't break anything by trying different things in mathematics the way you can in the real world. How to play intelligently is of course a matter of experience. It is hard to explain how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take
$$W=\begin{pmatrix}1&a\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
then $\mathrm{tr}W=2$. Take
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$$
then
$$AW=\begin{pmatrix}2&2a\\1&a+2\end{pmatrix}$$
and $\mathrm{tr}AW=4+a$.
Now, set $\sigma=\|A\|_{\mathrm{op}}$. You have
$$4+a\leq 2\sigma$$
where $\sigma$ is independent of $a$. This is clearly false for $a$ large enough.

Comment: Ok... thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. You could accept the answer, if that's what you were searching for.

Comment: I don't understand what happened, but I never wrote the first 4 lines (which are false: eigenvalues of W are all real and positive, as the characteristic polynomial is $(t-1)^2$ no matter what $a$ is...