# Spectral norm - trace inequality

Tags: matrices, trace, matrix-norms, linear-matrix-inequality, spectral-norm

I am wondering whether the following is true under which assumptions on A and B?
$\operatorname{trace}(AB)\leqslant\|A\| \operatorname{trace}(B)$

The matrix norm is the spectral norm here. Maybe [relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3103958/721644)

I tried to use the $\operatorname{trace}(AB)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\lambda_i,\lambda_i\in\sigma (AB)$, but then I need some relationship between eigs(AB) and eigs(A)*eigs(B), if I could have this, then because eigenvalues of A are less than its spectral norm, then the statement holds?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I saw this inequality used in a proof (for bounds of some matrix expressions) again and again but I just don't know why this is the case. Maybe this is relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103958/inequality-for-trace-of-product-of-matrices

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213246/721644)

Comment: Maybe you could use the fact that the trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues, see more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213246/721644).

Comment: [Also related, but regarding the Euclidean norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/374190/721644).

Comment: Any response from you, Stephanie?

Comment: Yes I tried to use the trace of AB is the sum of eigenvalues of AB, but then I need some relationship between eigs(AB) and eigs(A)*eigs(B), if I could have this, then because eigs(A) is less than its spectral norm, then the statement holds?

Comment: Include that into your question, please.

Comment: What does eigs denote? Spectrum or?

Comment: eigs means eigenvalues, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This certainly isn't true. Consider $A=B=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$ for instance. It is true, however, when $B$ is positive semidefinite. This follows directly from von Neumann's trace inequality $\operatorname{tr}(AB)\le\sum_i\sigma_i(A)\sigma_i(B)$:
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{tr}(AB)
\le\sum_i\sigma_i(A)\sigma_i(B)
\le\sum_i\|A\|\sigma_i(B)
=\sum_i\|A\|\lambda_i(B)
=\|A\|\operatorname{tr}(B).
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thanks! Do we also need real matrices A and B to be symmetric?

Comment: @Stephanie We need $B$ to be symmetric (real positive semidefinite matrices are by definition symmetric), but $A$ can be any general real square matrix.

Comment: I see thanks again!